# Can CacheBuilder replace MapMaker in my case?

Tags: java, caching, guava

I need to obtain the result of the slow method `slowResult()` for instances of the class `Something`. Caching alone doesn't help as the instances hardly ever repeat. Fortunately, I know that the result depends actually only on some easily obtained `Attributes` of `Something`, so I could use a `Map<Attributes, Result>` as a cache, in code

```
Result fastResult(Something something) {
    final Attributes attributes = attributesFor(something)
    Result result = cache.get(attributes);
    if (result!=null) return result;
    result = something.slowResult();
    cache.put(attributes, result);
    return result;
}
```

In order to keep the cache limited I used the now deprecated methods `maximumSize` and `expireAfterAccess`. The deprecation comes because of the new class `CacheBuilder` to be used instead. However, I've found no nice way how to apply it to my case. The cache keys need to be instances of `Attributes`, but in cache loading an instance of `Something` is needed and there's no easy way to recreate it from the `Attributes`.

Is there a *nice* solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one way to state this problem is, "how can I compare `Attributes.equals()` for the cache, but still have access to `Something` to create the value".  So, I think this might work ...

```
class SomethingKey {
  private Something something;
  private final Attributes attributes;
  SomethingKey(Something s) {
    this.something = s;
    this.attributes = attributesFor(something);
  }
  public Result createResult() {
    Something something = this.s;
    this.s = null;
    return something.slowResult();
  }
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o==this) return true;
    if(o==null || o.getClass() != this.getClass) return false;
    SomethingKey that = (SomethingKey)o;
    return this.attributes.equals(that.attributes);
  }
}
```

And then `CacheLoader.load` is basically

```
Result load(SomethingKey k) {
   return k.createResult();
}
```

And the map would be

```
Cache<SomethingKey,Result> map = ...;
```

Of course, the downside is you're creating a new SomethingKey per request, but...

Comment: In my case it's fine, because of the huge cost of calling `slowResult`. If `Something` was a huge object, it'd be a problem, too.

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting!  I don't think we had ever heard of a case like this.

For 11.0 you'll be able to do `cache.asMap().put()`, so it would probably be okay to just ignore the deprecation warnings for now. We are considering *possibly* enabling that in a 10.1 patch release because several users seem to be in a similar boat.

But, in 11.0 the other idea we're kicking around would allow you to do this:

```
Result fastResult(final Something something) {
  return cache.get(
      attributesFor(something),
      new Callable<Result>() {
        public Result call() {
          return something.slowResult();
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: Using `cache.asMap().put` needs also checking `contains` first, which is OK for me. The two arguments `put` looks better. Actually, the perfect solution for me would be `Cache.get2(K key, A attributes)`, where `key` and `attributes` would get used for lookup and passed to the loader, respectively. So the `CacheLoader`'s first type parameter would possible differ from the key type. But I don't think it'd get used often enough.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just key the Cache off of Something instead?

Comment: No... as I wrote "result depends actually only on some easily obtained `Attributes` of `Something`". Whenever the `Attributes` are the same I need to return the same `Result`, caching on `Something` doesn't help as it (unlike the `Attributes` obtained from it) hardly ever repeats.